# Date rule designer

Tags: usability, website-design

I need to make some kind of date rule designer in a web project. What does this mean? Imagine that the user has a date A, which is basically a dynamic date, and has to set up a second date (B) based on the first.

Imagine something like this: Send an email to my client 2 workdays after my client receives package. (Package receive date = Date A, Email sent date = Date B)

I will give out a few examples:

- Date B should be defaulted to Date A + 10 days
- Date B should be defaulted to Date A + 10 workdays
- Date B should be defaulted to Date A + 2 weeks
- Date B should be defaulted to Date A - 10 days
- Date B should be defaulted to Date A - 10 workdays
- Date B should be defaulted to Date A - 2 weeks

Thing is, that there is actually multiple dates that B can depend on, so what we did until now looked (ugly) something like this:

**Textbox1 + Dropdown1 + Dropdown2 + Dropdown 3**

- Textbox1 was where the user specified the difference
- Dropdown1 was for : day / weekday / month / week / year
- Dropdown2 was for : before / after
- Dropdown3 was for : select date A / C / D / F (also in here we added a few other values, like first day of month, second monday of month, n-th day of month etc etc)

Did anyone ever see anything like this? I wonder if we can make this somehow a lot more user-friendly than it is right now with the "4 web control" version.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if I get what you're saying it would look something like this. See below.

[image]

**The best way to proceed would be to reduce the number of dropdown menu's used.**

> Drop-down menus are often more trouble than they are worth and can be
>   confusing because Web designers use them for several different
>   purposes. Also, scrolling menus reduce usability when they prevent
>   users from seeing all their options in a single glance.

Source: [Drop-Down Menus: Use Sparingly](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/drop-down-menus-use-sparingly/)

Try something like this. See image below.

- Reduce cognitive load by having a pre-fill text with the most common input (>90%).
- The second dropbox has only two options so replace it with a picker
- Maybe try and use only one text field where the user enters the complete sentence and your system analyses and processes it in a way Slack(bot) handles new reminders.

[image]

Source: [Slack Help Center](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/208423427-Set-a-reminder)

[image]

Comment: This (your 2nd image) is interesting, and I personally really like it. I actually had built something like this. The reactions were not as I expected. The problem was when the textbox was empty, user "might not know what to write in them", because all this is like "writing code, user has to learn programming language". I do not agree with that, I would really prefer this way, but I was told otherwise.

Comment: Your 3rd image seems a lot more complex than my idea (your 1st image). Thanks for the help though !

Comment: @Ash I get that. For the second image you need some context for the user. Guide him while filling out the text field by either having a placeholder of subtitle text.